# Optional Parameter in mod_rewrite (pretty url)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do the following:

Access `user.php?lang=$1&id=$2&title=$3`

via

`en/user/1/tyler` (for English language)

and

`user/1/tyler` (without language parameter)

My rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^(en)(?:/(user)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*))?/?$ user.php?lang=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(user)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?$ user.php?lang=&id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It works when I put the language (en) on the front and I can retrieve all the parameters via $_GET but it doesn't work without it.

How could I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en)/user/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?lang=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?lang=&id=$1&title=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

It is important to turn off `MultiViews` to avoid using content negotiation service in Apache that may override mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes, my server got confused naming two files with the same names in different folders. Changing user.php to profile.php did the trick. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Have a nice day